# odbc DSN string for MS Access DB works only with php5.4

Tags: php, database, ms-access, odbc

i'm trying to connect to an old Access database (`c:\content.mdb`) using the odbc driver `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)` version 10.00.22624.01 (installed from this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

The connection string i'm using is the following: `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\content.mdb; Uid=; Pwd=;`

If i try to connect with an ancient php version (php **v5.4.45**, which has odbc extension v1.0), everything is fine.

If i try to connect with a "modern" php version (php **v8.1.12** with odbc extension v8.1.12) or any DBMS supporting odbc (eg DBeaver v22.2.4, which uses `jdbc:odbc`), i get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

The connection string (hence the odbc driver used) is **exactly the same**. Using php's `PDO` or `odbc_*` functions yields the same results.

So why is this happening? **Why does it work with php 5.4 but fails with anything else?**

Comment: This is likely entirely related to bitness, with modern systems being 64 bits by default. The old *.mdb driver is not installed from the link you provided, but is present on windows by default and only available for 32-bits programs, use the more modern mdb/accdb driver.

Comment: hello mr Erik and thank you! that was the problem! 
For future reference, i installed the x64 driver from the same link, and then changed the DSN to use the driver `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)`.
Then it worked both with php8 and Dbeaver (which are x64). Thanks again!